# Clustering Categorical Values in R

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis

I need to cluster mixed data(2 columns: 1 - numerical and 2 - string). Is there a package in R or python which will handle clustering of mixed data or categorical data?

Thanks!

Comment: A good starting point might be the CRAN task view: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

Answer (score 0):

With R I suggest the use of the `daisy` function from the `cluster` package.

You can have a `matrix` of mixed data types, nominal-ordinal-numeric.

If the data is mixed it computes the `gower` distance for each variable, basically each nominal values is converted to numeric, and the dissimilarity is measured by weighet mean of the contribution of each.

It can be used even if all variables are numeric, in which case it will use the standard metrics.

See [the help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.0.7-1/topics/daisy) for more information and examples.

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gower/vignettes/intro.html) an introduction to the gower distance.